# Why is contenteditable not a style?

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I was recently fiddling with `contenteditable` in a webpage and got irritated when I needed to set a large number of `span` tags with it (I ended up using JavaScript to do it). If only I could set it via CSS...

Does anyone know the rationale behind why `contenteditable` was designed as an attribute rather than a style?

Comment: you could have put a `div` around the spans and give that `div` `contentEditable`, as `contentEditable` is inherited down all apans would have been editable as well.

Comment: I didn't want edits 'overflowing' outside each span element.

Comment: In order to use contentEditable you *need* javascript to read back the edited contents, so I don't understand why it bothers you to use it to enable the editing.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Most people would argue that `contentEditable` defines behaviour, rather than style (which is true).

WebKit has a CSS property that is similar to `contentEditable`: [`-webkit-user-modify`](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-user-modify).

Answer (score 23):

try

```
span {
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write;
    -moz-user-modify: read-write;
    user-modify: read-write;
}
```

it worked on Firefox, Chrome. You can find more info about [user-modify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-user-modify)

Answer (score 9):

The ability for the user to edit some content or not isn't anything to do with presentation.

Answer (score 9):

styles are optional; you can (in theory) render every page without CSS and it should still work fine. In fact, that's what many text-only browsers, or audio-only browsers do.

`contentEditable` changes the *behavior* of elements. A browser that doesn't use style, but interprets JavaScript, should still benefit from the property.